# Maven build shows compilation error but Eclipse doesn't

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am facing a strange issue with Maven, looking for some help. My maven pom looks like this:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.californium</groupId>
   <artifactId>californium-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And added repository like this:

```xml
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repo.eclipse.org</id>
        <name>Californium Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/californium/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And Java class looks like this:

```
import org.eclipse.californium.core.CoapResource;
import org.eclipse.californium.core.CoapServer;
import org.eclipse.californium.core.server.resources.CoapExchange;

public class Hello extends CoapServer {
   //Code here
}
```

Problem is Eclipse doesn't throw any error, but when I try to run maven build from eclipse, I keep on getting many compilation errors like this:

> [ERROR] D:\Pradeep\Workspaces\coap\CoapServer\src\main\java\com\pradeep\coap\server\CoapServer\CoapProxyServer.java:[3,35] error: package org.eclipse.californium.core does not exist

I verified if dependencies downloaded correctly by removing `dependency` tag, then even eclipse throws error, so I assume it means dependencies are downloaded correctly (I also see the jar files in Maven dependencies in eclipse). I am facing this issue while running build. Can anyone please guide me in this?

Comment: Why are you using test as scope for your dependency? The code you copied here is a test class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Hello` class is in your source folder whereas you defined the dependency in scope `test`.  Either move your class to `src/test/java` our change your dependency not to be a test dependency.

Eclipse cannot distinguish between the scopes and puts everything on the classpath for the whole module, regardless of the defined scope.